# How to create a new column in r dataframe based on str values with if else statement?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I would like to add a column that contains 2 values (either beverage or food) given the input values fed into contitional statement:

Reference code:

```
updated_df$Item <- ifelse(updated_df$`Category Name` == c('Diet Soda', 'Diet Soda Can', 'Hydration/Sports', 'Energy', 'Flavored Noncarb', 'Juice', 'Milk', 'New Age Beverage', 'Probiotic Beverage', 'RTD Coffee', 'Soda', 'Soda Can', 'Sparkling Beverage', 'Tea', 'Vitamin Enhanced', 'Water'), 'Beverage', ifelse(updated_df$`Category Name` == c('Candy', 'Cookies', 'Crackers', 'Food', 'Gum/Mints', 'Meat Sticks', 'Nutrition Bar', 'Nuts/Trailmix', 'Pastry', 'Salty Snacks'), 'Food'))
```

I get the following error when I ran this statement:

```
Error in ifelse(updated_df$`Category Name` == c("Candy", "Cookies", "Crackers",  : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! New to R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need code like this:

```
df$new <- ifelse(test1, 'A', ifelse(test2, 'B', 'C'))
```

At the moment you are missing that C option. If you only have two categories, you can simplify it to:

```
df$new <- ifelse(test1, 'A', 'B')
```

Your next issue is that you are testing if category name is equal to the whole of those long lists and I guess you want to test if it is equal to one of the entries. You want:

```
df$value %in% c('a', 'b', 'c')
```

So in your specific case:

```
drinks <- c('Diet Soda', 'Diet Soda Can', 'Hydration/Sports', 
            'Energy', 'Flavored Noncarb', 'Juice', 'Milk', 
            'New Age Beverage', 'Probiotic Beverage', 'RTD Coffee', 
            'Soda', 'Soda Can', 'Sparkling Beverage', 'Tea', 
            'Vitamin Enhanced', 'Water')
updated_df$Item <- ifelse(updated_df$`Category Name` %in% drinks, 'Beverage', 'Food')
```

Comment: Okay. I just want every row to have either food or beverage based on the if else statement (either water or snack). I'm not sure what to change based on your input but i appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Perfect - as you sent that I realized subsetting by variables could do it. Thank you!